# Visual Composer boxed view

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I haven't been working with Visual Composer for ages. So my problem is I don't even know how to set up my page.php properly.

I am creating from scratch. I have Bootstrap included and the newest version of Visual Composer installed in my wordpress. I want to have this option:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkDYWXwQIJg

As for now my content is always fullwidth. I want my content to be in boxed view but have the option to stretch the rows like in the video. My page.php so far looks like this:

```
<?php 
define('THEME_TEMPLATE', TRUE);
define('IS_FULLWIDTH', TRUE);
get_header();?>
<div id="contentarea">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

So I would appreciate your help. How should my page.php look like if I want to achieve the look of the video. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you correctly you want to achieve the stretch row facility of Visual Composer.

In that case your contenarea div should have the boxed width in css -

```
@contentarea {
    width: 1170px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Also the contentarea's overflow should be visible since Visual Composer used to overflow the div when in full width.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot. I'm so dumb.

Comment: Your'e Welcome. :) If that helped would you please accept this as an answer in here please?